# Convert Excel Data into a HTML Graph

Tags: java, vba, graph

Evening,

I have a spreadsheet with sheets full of data and I want to produce external HTML pages displaying graphs created from the data on the sheets. I currently only have 4 pages but that will rise to about 20.

Now I am ok with visual basic and I am currently teaching myself Java. But what would be the best way to do this ? The spreadsheet is quite big already so was hoping to get ideas on how to do it external to the existing spreadsheet.

Not coming up with a a great deal of information as i don't which way would be better.

Comment: What is an "HTML graph"?  You can chart data and export those charts as image files, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I have edited the question to try and make more sense

Comment: Save as HTML from Excel?

Comment: The spreadsheet is quite large to start, adding charts to it will probably make it really large. Was hoping for a solution external to the existing spreadsheet. Can I do it in Java ?

Comment: I'm sure it could be done in Java (though I'm not a Java programmer there are Java solutions for reading/writing Excel files)

Comment: I have written code to convert an Excel page to HTML. Can you drop an example page somewhere that I can test? If it works, you can have the code.

Comment: @StureS yes please.

Comment: Well, where's your Excel page?

Comment: @StureS Sorry was having fun trying to share the file but i have now done it. http://www.filedropper.com/sample_286

Comment: That was not a graph, it was a plain table. You can save it as HTML directly.